# Bluemix Secure Gateway Client - Fail to connect Tunnel

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I have installed docker inside internal server it requires ibm bluemix docker client.

Use the command below.

```
  docker run -it ibmcom/secure-gateway-client <id> -t <security_token>
```

But it only returns.

How do i fix and debug the issue ?

[image]